# How to load Google Map pins faster

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have Google Map which currently contains 5 pins in one var.

Why if I have many locations in my var, then the map is loading very slow?

**My point is:**
How I can speed up loading my Google Map if I have over 100 pins on same map?

Code:

```
<div id='main_map'></div>
<script>
var map;
var markers = [];
var locations = [['content of the popup', 51.248016, 22.567579, '3'],'content of the popup', 21.248016, 22.567579, '3'],'content of the popup', 31.248016, 22.567579, '2'],'content of the popup', 41.248016, 22.567579, '7'],'content of the popup', 71.248016, 22.567579, '3'],];
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var pinBase = '/static/img/user/pin-';

function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('main_map') {
    zoom: 2, center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},
      map: map,
      html: locations[i][0],
      id: i,
      icon: pinBase + locations[i][3] + '.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        id: this.id,
        content: this.html,
        position: this.getPosition()
      });
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      smoothZoom(this.getMap(), 13, map.getZoom());

      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, 'closeclick', function(){
        markers[this.id].setVisible(true);
      });

      this.setVisible(true);
      infowindow.open(map);
    });

    let toggleMarkers = (checkbox) => {
      var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
      markers.map((elem) => {
        elem.setVisible(isChecked);
      });
    }

  }

}

initMap();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using async? You would need to put your script in an external file but it should load faster https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

Comment: @codeKracken Sure, but mostly I have connected this map to PHP and I think it will not be the case here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open only one infowindow at a time google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951991/open-only-one-infowindow-at-a-time-google-maps) - see my answer there; creating only 1 infowindow object should speed up your script.

Comment: The posted code has syntax errors (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`). If you have lots of markers and load your marker data asynchronously, the map will load faster (it won't need to wait for the large locations array to load as part of your page).  You can look at the example in the documentation: [Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps), which uses AJAX to load marker data from a database.